# ASP.NET Application Running Slow

Tags: asp.net, performance

There's a web app I've been assigned to, which is running very slow.  It is a site that sells products so it is database driven, however even pages that do not query the database are loading very slow.  The pages use master pages, and the code is in VB.NET

I checked with fiddler and the time it takes to load basic (non database driven) pages are about 5.5 seconds on average.

What are some tools that can help me determine the cause of the slow speeds, and any recommendations as to how to speed it up, or potential issues that could cause it?

### Update

So I messed around with the code piece by piece as I wasn't getting anywhere with these tools.  As soon as I remove master pages, and I include the same code that's on the master pages in the .aspx page itself, the speed improves drastically (approximately 5 times faster load times).

What might cause the master pages to cause load times to slow down so much?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page? There could be a thousand reasons why. Where is it hosted?

Comment: Is this ASP.NET or classic ASP? VBScript would seem to indicate the latter.

Comment: it's ASP.NET -- it's hosted internally.  I'm also asking for tips for tools and whatnot that can help determine the reasons since there could be a thousand.

Comment: In its current form, this question is impossible to answer. Voting to close as 'not a real question' because of it: *This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form*.

Comment: @George Stocker: edited to a valid, answerable question.

Comment: @Sev It's ASP.NET, but written in VBScript? I didn't know VBScript compiled into an ASP.NET application.

Comment: @George Stocker:  I guess I meant Vb.NET I apologize for the nomenclature issue.

Comment: Can you tell me what version of Windows the server is running?

Comment: Have you checked the available RAM on the server?

Comment: @citronas: 2.5 gigs out of 4 are available.  also, there's another site hosted on the same server which runs perfectly fine.  it seems to be pointing to a programmatic issue but it's giving me difficulties to pin-point the problem given that i didn't write the code.

Answer (score 4):

If it's mainly front-end performance issues you can always check out [Steve Souder's rules](http://stevesouders.com/hpws/rules.php) on how to improve that. At least it can look faster to the user.

If you do use Firebug, there is a plugin for it that incorporates these rules - [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) which is quite useful.

Answer (score 3):

The [ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) can conduct code-level timings to see where most of the time is spent. You can also use `Response.Write()` and time each method to do this manually.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to mess around with `Response.Write()` to get a breakdown of method timing: simply add the `Trace="true"` attribute to a page's `@Page` directive as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94c55d08.aspx

That will give you a breakdown of the time elapsed in each event of the page's lifecycle.

If you need finer measurement within an event (e.g. all the time is in `Page_Load()` and that does a bunch of different things), you can add `Trace.Write()` calls like this:

```
Trace.Write("category name", "your message");
```

Put a few of those throughout a long-running method and you can see which step is taking the time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use firebug for firefox, I believe it's available for a few browsers. You can see all of the files that are being received, how much time each one takes and the file size.

Comment: @Sev, check the codebehind on the masterpage, maybe it is doing some intensive things? All the master page is doing is taking the child page and rendering it as if you had the code in it to begin with. There shouldn't be any performance issues. Do you have any user controls on the masterpage that have data intensive things going on?

Comment: i'm looking into them.  I noticed the master page registered a control that the main page also registered...I wonder how much of an effect that might have?

Comment: @Sev, I imagine if the tag prefix for both was the same it would throw an error, if they were different it might try to load twice?